# fs.writeFile does not write file data recieved from request.data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I want to write file data received from `request.data`.
It show that file is written and a file with filename is created on disk. but when I open file there is no content.

**This is the angular.js code**

```js
    $scope.sendImage = function (files) {
        if (files && files.length) {
            $scope.isFileSelected = true;
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                var file = files[i];
                var dateString = formatAMPM(new Date());
                console.log("file sending...");
                var imageData;
                var fr = new FileReader();
                if (FileReader && files && files.length) {
                    console.log("im inside");          
                  fr.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
                  fr.onload = function () {
                    imageData = fr.result;
                    console.log("im here inside sendImage : ", fr.result);     
                    console.log("type of data in file",typeof(imageData));  
                    $http.post($rootScope.baseUrl + "/uploadImage",{ filecontent : imageData, filename : file.name}, function (res){
                        console.log(res);
                    });    
                  };
                }



                // var fd = new FormData();
                //Take the first selected file
                // fd.append("file", file);

                $socket.emit('send-message',{ username : $rootScope.username, userAvatar : $rootScope.userAvatar, hasFile : $scope.isFileSelected , sendfile : "", istype : "image", msgTime : dateString },function (data){
                    // console.log("inside console",data);
                });
            }
        }
    };
```

**this is the angular service call**

```
angular.module('Services',[])
.service('sendImageService', function ($http, $rootScope) {
    this.sendImage = function (file) {
         return $http.post( $rootScope.baseUrl + '/uploadImage', file, {
                transformRequest: angular.identity,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
            }).then(function (response) {
                return response;
            });

    };

});
```

**this is the node.js code**

```
app.post('/uploadImage',function (req, res){
    // console.log(req.body);
    var filename = Date.now() + req.body.filename;
    var filecontent = req.body.filecontent;
    var filecontent = filecontent.substring(filecontent.indexOf(',')+1);
    console.log("type of data in file ",typeof(filecontent));
    var file_buffer = new Buffer(filecontent);
    fs.writeFile("./public/app/upload/images/"+filename, file_buffer, function(){
        console.log("done writting");
                //res.end();
    });
    res.send({"success" : "res from server"});


});
```

I am getting file in `request.body` in string format but `fs.writeFile` does not  write file properly.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can't save a dataURL as a text file and expect an image to show up. split the dataURL on "," and call `atob(thatArray[1])` to get the binary data back from the url. you might also need to parse the object you POSTed
.

Comment: Is the file really empty?

Comment: image file is blank. error message in the image viewer is not a png or jpeg file.